# Grab characters before a specific word in string/cookie

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have a cookie (_gaexp), which I want to extract values from:

`GAX1.3.yK3HnOfSRZCVUMNkK3tVCA.18961.ss12!QV1ffpISQcCGmM4IOTuUlQ.18961.0!F9l4roGRR5K03cSaZMWQiA.18961.1`

I specifically want to extract the characters, before `18961` **only**, which I can do.
But I don't want `GAX1.3` included in my result.

For example, I have the following code:

```
let read  = readCookie("_gaexp").split("!");
read.forEach(function(key, index) {
    splitBeginningOfCookie = read[0].split('.')
    optimizeID = splitBeginningOfCookie[3];
    
    let variantID = key.split(optimizeID+".")[1];
    let id = key.split("."+optimizeID)[0];
    console.log("variantID", variantID);
    console.log("id", id);
});
```

Which console.logs:

```
variantID ss12
id GAX1.3.yK3HnOfSRZCVUMNkK3tVCA

variantID 0
id QV1ffpISQcCGmM4IOTuUlQ

8 variantID 1
id F9l4roGRR5K03cSaZMWQiA
```

I want to exclude `GA1.3.` from the first loop though.  What is the best way, to grab the long IDs only, from this string?

The last 2 loops are fine.  It's just the first one, which returns everything before `18961`.

Thanks,

Comment: You could replace 'GAX1.3' with ''?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `split()` you could use a regex to grab the two sections around `.18961.`. In this scenario you could use the regex:

```regex
([^.]+)\.18961\.([^.]+)
```

[image: regex diagram]
<sup>[regexper.com](https://regexper.com/#%28%5B%5E.%5D%2B%29%5C.18961%5C.%28%5B%5E.%5D%2B%29)</sup>

```js
const cookie = "GAX1.3.yK3HnOfSRZCVUMNkK3tVCA.18961.ss12!QV1ffpISQcCGmM4IOTuUlQ.18961.0!F9l4roGRR5K03cSaZMWQiA.18961.1";
const regex = /([^.]+)\.18961\.([^.]+)/;

const read = cookie.split("!");
read.forEach((part, index) => {
  const [_, id, variantID] = part.match(regex);
  
  console.log("variantID", variantID);
  console.log("id", id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
var v = 'GAX1.3.yK3HnOfSRZCVUMNkK3tVCA';
var result = v.replace('GA','').replace('1.3.','');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes, it's as simple as that, but I think `GA1.3.` was a typo, so it should be `result = v.replace('GAX1.3.', '');` or perhaps `result = v.replace(/^GAX1\.3\./, '');`.

Comment: The actually needed result is to remove the only GA1.3. not GAX1.3., that's why it's a little bit complex.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with a help of RegExp:

```js
const data = "GAX1.3.yK3HnOfSRZCVUMNkK3tVCA.18961.ss12!QV1ffpISQcCGmM4IOTuUlQ.18961.0!F9l4roGRR5K03cSaZMWQiA.18961.1";
const reg = /([^.!]+)\.18961\.([^!]+)/g;
const result = {};
let d;
while((d = reg.exec(data)))
  result[d[1]] = d[2];

console.log(result);
```

Or using `matchAll()`

```js
const data = "GAX1.3.yK3HnOfSRZCVUMNkK3tVCA.18961.ss12!QV1ffpISQcCGmM4IOTuUlQ.18961.0!F9l4roGRR5K03cSaZMWQiA.18961.1";
const reg = /([^.!]+)\.18961\.([^!]+)/g;
const result = [...data.matchAll(reg)].reduce((r,a)=>{return r[a[1]]=a[2],r},{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for taking the time to comment with some solutions and answers!  Unfortunately, i can't accept all of them as an answer, but they are great and i'll play around with each one.  Thank you so much!  This is really helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Split each string at every dot inside the `read` array into a new array called say, `cookieParts`.

   ```
    read.forEach(e => {
      let cookiePart = e.split('.');
    }
   ```
2. Instead of using a hard-coded number `[3]` for getting the `variantID`, just get the last index of each split string instead.

   ```
    read.forEach(e => {
      let cookiePart = e.split('.');
      let variantID = cookiePart[cookiePart.length - 1];
    }
   ```
3. Use the [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to check if the split string has `GAX1.3` or not and if it does, log the third element to the console else log the first element to the console.

   ```
    read.forEach(e => {
      let cookiePart = e.split('.');
      let variantID = cookiePart[cookiePart.length - 1];

      console.log("variantID", variantID);

      if(e.includes('GAX1.3')) {
        console.log('id', cookiePart[2]);
      } else {
        console.log('id', cookiePart[0]);
      }
    }
   ```

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
const cookie = 'GAX1.3.yK3HnOfSRZCVUMNkK3tVCA.18961.ss12!QV1ffpISQcCGmM4IOTuUlQ.18961.0!F9l4roGRR5K03cSaZMWQiA.18961.1';

let read = cookie.split("!");

read.forEach(e => {
  let cookiePart = e.split('.');
  let variantID = cookiePart[cookiePart.length - 1];
  let id = e.includes('GAX1.3') ? cookiePart[2] : cookiePart[0];

  console.log("variantID", variantID);
  console.log("id", id);
});
```

**P.S.** In the above snippet, I used a ternary operator instead of an if/else statement for retrieving the `id` based on whether `GAX1.3` is present or not. You can replace the ternary operator with an if/else statement in case you prefer *if/else* over *ternary*.